# Iterate through Vue component fields

Tags: json, typescript, vue.js

I have a Vue component with lots of properties (> 40). It is a form for editing some business entity. The flow is the following:

1. On mounted() load the data as json from server and initialize component properties
2. Edit the data as required
3. Put all the properties into json structure and send back to server to update data

The properties in my component are named exactly the same as in json structure. I want to iterate through properties in my component and create json structure with 1 line of code instead of doing something like this:

```
var data = {
 field1 = this.field1,
 field2 = this.field2,
 field3 = this.field3
 ...
 field40 = this.field40
}
```

I use TS and **vue-class-component**, so the component code looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component({
  template: ...
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  field1: Number = null;
  field2: Date = null;
  field3: String = null;
  ...
  field40: Number = null;

  mounted() {
    axios.get(..., response => {
      this.field1 = response.data.field1
      this.field2 = response.data.field2
      this.field3 = response.data.field3
      ...
      this.field40 = response.data.field40
    }
  }

  submit() {
    const data = {
      field1 = this.field1,
      field2 = this.field2,
      field3 = this.field3,
      ...
      field40 = this.field40,
    };

    axios.put(..., data);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two ways to do this.

Provide a list of properties in an array, if you know it in advance (this is better practice as the `data` property gets initiated in the right way):

```
const props=['field1','field2', ...];
export default {
  async mounted(){
     //load the data and ensure only the expected properties are mounted
     //this avoids any unexpected behaviour.
     const result = await loadMyData();
     for(let prop of props) this[prop]=result[prop];
  }
  data(){
    //instantiate the data object to ensure all the properties are reactive
    const data={};
    for(let prop of props) data[prop]=null;
    return data;
  }
  methods:{
    async updateServer(){
       //build the data object to send back to the server then send it.
       const data={};
       for(let prop of props) data[prop]=this[prop];
       await sendUpdate(data);
    }
  }
}
```

The second way is to store a list of properties when you load the data from the server using `Object.keys()` and store this as a data property.  You will then need to use `vm.$set` to ensure all of the properties have the correct reactivity, and you will not be able to have the properties at the root level, instead you will need to nest them (see [the vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties)).  However I assume that if your view object is designed to react to these properties then you must know them in advance.

Comment: Good idea, but I don't want to bring this props array, because I already have listed all my properties as the component fields

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use typescript and vue-class-component. Please see the updated question

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your fields in a model field in your data:

```
data:{ model:{}}
```

Then on mounted you could set reactive props in your model

```
  mounted(){
        for(let field in YOUR_JSON_OBJ){
           Vue.set(this.model, field , YOUR_JSON_OBJ[field])
        }
   }
```

Then when you need to submit form, just pass your vue model prop

```
YOUR_SUBMIT_METHOD(JSON.stringify(this.model))
```

Comment: I'll try this asap

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use typescript and vue-class-component. Please see the updated question